# Regex, Google Url , Php

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to detect a url in the form

```
http://google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http://grand-theft-auto-v.tk/Biggenius.php


 http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http://grand-theft-auto-v.tk/Biggenius.php

https://www.google.**com**/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http://grand-theft-auto-v.tk/Biggenius.php

http://www.google.**us**/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http://grand-theft-auto-v.tk/Biggenius.php
```

**My Regex**

```
 if(preg_match(" /(http|https):\/\/.*google\..+\/url\?sa=(.+)$/", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {

                include_once("Biggenius.htm");
                exit;
           }
```

But for some reasons regex patter is not working.Can anyone post Correct Regex For this?

Comment: "But for some reasons regex patter is not working." isn't an adequate statement of the problem. What output do you expect? What output do you get? What else have you tried? Help us help *you*.

Comment: Presumably you have already tested this with a testing tool like http://www.regextester.com/?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct, he's trying to make so only when you click on a specific Google link to his site, a page show up. I should note that people can fake referrers, so that's one way around it.

I think this RegEx should help you, [demo here](http://regexr.com?30ugm):

```
(http|https):\/\/(www.){0,1}google.[a-z.]+\/url\?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=10&ved=0CHoQFjAJ&url=http:\/\/grand-theft-auto-v.tk\/Biggenius.php
```